# How to truncate the last portion of a large text file

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to strip out the last `^` and line-feed at the end of a file. This code works great for small files, but not for very large ones. I was considering reading the file in chunks or perhaps just the last portion, but I'm not sure how to do that.

```
Dim text As String
Dim intLength As Integer
Dim strEnd As String

text = File.ReadAllText(pstrOutputFolder & "tblzTF2FORMS_" & pstrFormType & ".txt")
intLength = Len(text)
strEnd = Right(text, 2)
If strEnd = "^" & vbLf & "" Then
    intLength = intLength - 2
    text = Left(text, intLength)
    File.WriteAllText(pstrOutputFolder & "tblzTF2FORMS_" & pstrFormType & ".txt", text)
End If
```

Comment: Could try using `StreamReader` Class to read in the file as this won't keep the entire file in memory

Comment: This website might help you: [How to read the last few lines of a file in VB](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/59b8bc31-878d-4111-aa03-8abaab2a41e5/how-to-read-the-last-few-lines-of-a-file-in-vb?forum=vbgeneral)

Answer (score 1):

Reading the whole file in chunks, progressively writing all the data to a second temporary file (except the last two characters, of course) is going to be your best bet.  When you're using a `FileStream`, it is possible to seek to a given position and then overwrite individual bytes, but that only works when you are overwriting the data with new data of the same length.  That doesn't work when you are truncating.